# Sort string field as number (int)

Tags: solr

In my application, I have a solr string field which can contain values like A1, A2, A10, A100.

If I apply sort function in that field I am getting the result as A1, A10, A100, A2. But my intention is to get the sorting as natural number way like A1, A2, A10, A100 excluding the char part for my indexed value. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: What happens when a B30 or C20 occurs in that series?

Comment: One way to do that would be for you to store a separate field with the value normalized for sorting, e.g. value: "A1", normalized: "A00001". But you'll have to write that code.

Comment: @cheffe Actually I am trying to add sorting functionality to an existing application and data. For different type, there might be A30 and B30. But it's sure that I am not going to sort in a combined search result which contains A* and B*. So looking for some way where i can exclude the first char and can have an int sort.

Comment: @HectorCorrea is there a way to put that normalization or leading 'zero' padding in copy field?

Answer (score 2):

Or you introduce a new fieldtype and introduce a new comparator for that one, as described in this approach: http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2011/05/custom-sorting-in-solr-using-external.html (their use-case is a bit more complex, but the main logic with defining a field type, using a custom FieldComparatorSource in there providing a comparator should work for your case). 
Within the comparator you could then sort for length and then for value first or add some logic to distinguish the parts of the strings before sorting on them.